# How to enable javascript console.log()/error()/warn() in xulrunner applications?

Tags: javascript, console, mozilla, xulrunner

In a web page running in normal browsers, we can use `console.log()/error()/warn()` to print messages to the web console. However, in a page(html or xul) running in xulrunner application, it seems that `console.log()/error()/warn()` drop messages silently.

I set these prefs:

`pref("browser.dom.window.dump.enabled", true);
pref("javascript.options.showInConsole", true);`

and run xulrunner with `-console` or `-jconsole` options.

So, is it possible to enable javascript console.log/error/warn in xulrunner applications?

I known that `dump()` function works for xulrunner with `-console`, but it is not standard, and there are web pages out of my control running in my xulrunner applications.

For an example demostrating this problem, you can checkout `https://github.com/matthewkastor/XULRunner-Examples.git`, and run the 'browser' application with an web page using `console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XULRunner will drop messages passed to console.log() unless you attach a debugger to it. This can be achieved by remote debugging: XULRunner as debuggee, firefox as debugger. Once the debugger attached to the XULRunner app, you can see console.log()ed messages in the debugger.

[Instruction for remote debgging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Debugging_XULRunner_applications#Browser_Debugger) can be found at MDN.

You may also want to set `devtools.debugger.remote-enabled` pref of your firefox to `true`.

Use this code in your app:

```
  var windowtype = ...
  Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-server.jsm');
  DebuggerServer.chromeWindowType = windowtype;
  if (!DebuggerServer.initialized) {
    DebuggerServer.init();
    DebuggerServer.addBrowserActors(windowtype);
  }
  DebuggerServer.openListener(6000);
```

If your page is (x)html, assign `windowtype` with `null`; if your page is xul, assign `windowtype` with the same value of the windowtype attribute of the `xul:window` element:

```
  <xul:window windowtype=... >
  ...
  </xul:window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the nsIConsoleService.

For a simple log message :

```
function consoleLog(aMsg){
    var console;
    console = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"]
               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);
    console.logStringMessage(aMsg);
}

console.log('My important message');
```

Ref : [nsIConsoleService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIConsoleService) at MDN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But nsIConsoleService (1) is not API-compatible with CommonJS console and normal browsers' console implementation (2) can't be used in non-priviliged page. So I don't see the advantage over dump().